# Static methods and type parameters in Java Language Specification

Tags: java, static-methods, jls

I read in the JLS 7 the following sentence.

> It is a compile-time error to use the name of a type parameter of any surrounding
>   declaration in the header or body of a class method.

Please explain its meaning.

Comment: Add the link of JLS here. Otherwise, it's hard to know the context

Comment: I have a copy available at the office which I cannot share. This sentence appears in the section where static modifier for a method is explained.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html  point 8.4.3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means you can't do

```
class Test<T> {
    static void f(T a) {
    }
}
```

You have to do

```
class Test<T> {
    static <T> void f(T a) {
    }
}
```

The generic types of a static method are independent of generic types of the class or other methods.

So you can even do something like

```
class Test {
    static <A, B, C> void f(A a, B b, C c) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Paul, Thanks for the clarification. Does this mean I can use any other generic type in a static method than the one used by the class?